# Is Plue in Fairy Tail and in Rave the same?

Tags: fairy-tail, rave-master

Plue exists on both Hiro Mashima's manga *Rave Master* and *Fairy Tail*. Is Plue the same in Fairy Tail & Rave?

Plue in Rave:

[image]

Plue in FT:

[image]

Comment: along with Plue, Elie is also in both series

Comment: I don't remember seeing Elie in FT, except in FTxRave

Comment: Oh, I am mistaken. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Plue of Rave Master** is a stout, white creature, reminiscent of a snowman, that only comes up to three feet in height. Plue was born in the Kingdom of Symphonia, signifying he is a creature of some sort. [(Source: Rave Master Wiki)](http://ravemaster.wikia.com/wiki/Plue)

In contrast, **Plue aka Nikora**, "The Canis Minor" (ニコラ Nikora) is a Silver Key Celestial Spirit that has no obvious combat abilities. It is stated to usually be kept as a pet for low-powered Mages who is in contract with Lucy Heartfilia. [(Source: Fairy Tail Wiki)](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Plue)

Since both series have the same author, Mashima must've decided to use his own design again. But they are different, as one of them is a creature, while the other is a celestial spirit.

Comment: It's just a returning gag :P

Answer (score 0):

In the manga 'Monster Soul', it is mentioned that Plue appears in almost ALL of Hiro Mashima's mangas as camios.

Comment: Can you cite a source? A chapter number might also be helpful.